# D: drive network mapped to D: drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I was cleaning up my `D:` drive, deleting an old Google Drive I no longer use, and upon going deep into the folder tree, I found a folder to my `D:` drive *(not a shortcut, but an actual folder)*, with the folder listed as a network folder.

What is happening here and how do I fix this?

- Nested `D:` duplicate: [image: Nested duplicate D: folder]
- Nested `D:` contents: [image: Nested D: contents]
- Root of `D:`: [image: Root of D:]

UPDATE:
when I followed a comment telling me to check if the it's a symblink with the command 'ls'. Power shell tells me it's a directory

[Powershell in admin mode results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHImm.png)

when I call 'dir' in a cmd window. The results came back saying it's a directory. I also tried to use "rmdir" to remove the symblink without removing content and it told me something else was using the directory currently

[listing the contents of `../app`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwxAn.png)

[trying to remove the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACGLl.png)

Update 2:

I was able to remove the `../app/D:` directory when I booted into a linux distro and deleted the file. The issue has been resolved.

Comment: `..\app\D:` is likely a shortcut or symlink to `D:` - to verify, open a Powershell terminal within `..\app` and issue `ls` _(if it's a shortcut, you'll see the `Name` as `D:.lnk`, whereas if it's a symlink, it will show `D: -> D:`)_. It is not a Network Share per folder _Properties_. Removing it depends on whether it's a shortcut or symlink - if it's a shortcut, it can be deleted, but if it's a symlink and something within your `..\SE Jobs` directory relies on the symlink, it will cause config issues for the project.

Comment: Can you see something related when you run net use command?